# Access query SQL difference in dates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Ive searched for awhile and I have tried numerous calculations I've found but none seem to work.

In a query I'm trying to limit it to the results where (Positionsfilled.HSRT_duedate) is more than 365 when factoring today's.

HSRT_duedate is formatted to show dd-mm-yyyy

So if the due date is 12-05-2016 and today's date is 13-05-2016 then it'll show everyone that has a due date of 12-05-2016 or before.

Comment: I guess you mean a due date of 12-5-2015 (2015-05-12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try....

```
SELECT Positionsfilled.HSRT_duedate
FROM Positionsfilled
WHERE ((DateDiff("d",[HSRT_duedate],Date())>365));
```

Comment: I've tried that but for some reason it doesn't show the one record with a date of 03/11/2015. So I figured the code wasn't correct.

Comment: I figured it out, it was because I was using a calculated field which was 365 more... I literally had that code and spent close to 4 hours trying to figure out why it would t work. After seeing it posted I worked with it for awhile then realized exactly what was going on. The code is correct and thank you, without seeing someone else post this I would've probably never caught my mistake.